# Setting a thread priority to high C

Tags: multithreading, thread-priority

I am writing a program that will create two threads, one of them has to have a high pripoity and the other is default. I am using pthread_create() to create the thread and would like to initiate the thread priority from the same command. The way I am doing that is as follow:

pthread_create(&threads[lastThreadIndex], NULL, &solution, (void *)(&threadParam));

where,
threads: is an array of type pthread_t that has all my threads in.
lastThreadIndex: is a counter 
solution: is my function
threadParam: is a struct that has all variables needed by the solution function.

I have read many articles and most of them suggest to replace NULL with the priority level; However, I never found the level key word or the exact way of doing it.

Please help...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In POSIX, that second parameter is the pthread attribute, and `NULL` just means to use the default.

However, you can create your *own* attribute and set its properties, including driving up the priority with something like:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>

int rc;
pthread_attr_t attr;
struct sched_param param;

rc = pthread_attr_init (&attr);
rc = pthread_attr_getschedparam (&attr, &param);
(param.sched_priority)++;
rc = pthread_attr_setschedparam (&attr, &param);

rc = pthread_create (&threads[lastThreadIndex], &attr,
    &solution, (void *)(&threadParam));

// Should really be checking rc for errors.
```

Details on POSIX threading, including scheduling, can be found starting at [this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread.h.html).

Comment: Can you please provide a good reference to learn how to do this. The problem I am facing is that I have a program that deals with a matrix with 3200 dimension. I broke down the matrix into 4 sub matrices and sends each submatrix on a thread to be manipulated. The execution time I get on windows machine is 6521 microseconds (which is almost the same as the sequential code execution time 6600msec) ; However, when I run the same program on a linux machine it runs in 860 microseconds (the sequential code execution time on the linux machine is 6300msec).

Comment: @Anas, if you're using pthreads on windows, it's _probably_ pthreads_win32. If so, it's (how can I say this tactfully?) ... less optimised than the Linux kernel, based on my experience :-) You may be better off using Windows native threads.

Comment: Do you mean open MP on windows ? or there is another way ?

Comment: @Anas: No, I mean things like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx